get all combinations of paths of a string in java
I have an input string that looks like: /some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
I wish to extract all possible subpaths in reverse order from this, i.e:
/some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
/some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc
/some/path/aaa/bbb
/some/path/aaa
/some/path
/some

private static String EXAMPLE = "/some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> allPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder = getAllPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder(EXAMPLE);
        System.out.println(allPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder);
    }

    private static List<String> getAllPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder(String fullPath) {
// some magic
    }

Would return ["/some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd", "/some/path/aaa/bbb/ccc", "/some/path/aaa/bbb", "/some/path/aaa", "/some/path", "/some"]
I have been trying to do some kind of split() and adding the Nth element of the split to the Nth element of the array, but I fill like there is something smarter.
 private static List<String> getAllPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder(String fullPath) {
        String[] split = fullPath.split("/");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(split.length);
        int counter = split.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            
        }
        return result;
    }

Is there a way to get all combinations of paths?

"I wish" noted. "Is there a way to get all combinations of paths?" yes. The split seems like a good start. Don't give up. Keep going. You may want to review [ask] at some point.

( first can be resolved using Path like in var p = Path.of(EXAMPLE);while (!p.equals(p.getRoot())) { System.out.println(p); p = p.getParent();} - very simplified, no error handling... Obviously only applcable for file system paths [output will be OS dependant] )

Upvoted, this is also quite efficient

There are several ways to adress this
You can use build the different strings from shorter prefix to longer, and add them in a list from the beginning to get your reverse order
private static List<String> getAllPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder(String fullPath) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part : fullPath.replaceFirst("/", "").split("/")) {
        prefix.append("/").append(part);
        result.add(0, prefix.toString());
    }
    return result;
}

You can also split the string from the beginning until the last /, but finding the / before the previous one on each iteration
private static List<String> getAllPossibleSubpathInReverseOrder(String fullPath) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = fullPath.lastIndexOf('/');
    while (index > 0) {
        result.add(fullPath.substring(0, index));
        index = fullPath.lastIndexOf('/', index - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

